# How to select the highest record (semester) for each student ID with names, course names, and scores using SQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve the highest record (semester) for each student ID, along with their names, the corresponding course names, and the scores obtained in each semester from a database using SQL and PHP. I have the following table structure:

Table: records

| StudentID | StudentName | CourseName | Semester | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Math | 1 | 85 |
| 1 | John | Math | 2 | 92 |
| 1 | John | Math | 3 | 88 |
| 2 | Emma | Science | 1 | 79 |
| 2 | Emma | Science | 2 | 87 |
| 3 | Adam | History | 1 | 92 |

I want to retrieve only the rows with the highest semester for each student ID, including their names, the corresponding course names, and the scores obtained in the highest semester. In this case, the desired result would be:

| StudentID | StudentName | CourseName | Semester | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Math | 3 | 88 |
| 2 | Emma | Science | 2 | 87 |
| 3 | Adam | History | 1 | 92 |

What would be the most efficient SQL query to achieve this? Additionally, how can I implement this logic in PHP to display the results?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: URL-only questions are discouraged. The image hosted on a third-party website might not be available in the future.

Comment: I know that, but I don't have enough reputation to be able which upload image on StackOverFlow.

Comment: @NikosM. Thank you for adding the image inline.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058170/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-the-student-who-got-max-marks-in-each-subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *  
FROM STUDENT_SCORE  
GROUP BY student_id  
HAVING MAX(score)
```

Note: If you need id renamed to `stnd_tbl_nd`, you can do that before or after a projection using `AS` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

```
select s1.* from  student s1
inner join 
(
    select student_id,max(semester) as semester
    from  student group by student_id
) as  s2 
on s1.student_id=s2.student_id and s1.semester=s2.semester
```